# SSRS R2 2012 Split string in two columns

Tags: reporting-services, substring, ssrs-2012

I have a problem with SSRS 2012
I have to split this string 201706 (that means year and month) in two columns to show only month (06) and year (2017).
Can someone help me?

**i return this column by a dataset that i can't modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field IS a string then you can use `LEFT` and `MID` for this.

Just set the expression for the columns to be

```
=LEFT(Fields!myFieldName.Value, 4)
```

this just gets the left 4 characters and

```
=MID(Fields!myFieldName.Value, 5,2)
```

this just gets the part of the string that starts at position 5 and is 2 characters long.

If you field is not a string then you can convert it to a sting first using `CStr` so replace `Fields!myFieldName.Value` with `CStr(Fields!myFieldName.Value)`